# Why couldn't Mob stop Dash Granny?

Tags: mob-psycho-100

Apparently, Mob couldn't stop the Dash Granny because she wasn't a ghost but a real person? But Mob can exert his psychic powers over ghosts and humans, so why couldn't Mob stop Dash Granny?

Answer (score 2):

From the anime, we know that he won't use his power against humans. There is one reason why he couldn't stop Dash Granny.

This is speculation. The other reason I can think of is because there is a different type of psychic power to be used against humans or ghosts. So, when he tries to use his psychic power to manipulate ghosts against Dash Granny, it seems that it doesn't have any effect. That's why he knows that Dash Granny is not a ghost.

Comment: Hi. Do you have evidence from the manga/anime to support your second claim or is this just pure speculation?

Comment: CMIIW, but I think mob did say "it doesn't work" to Reigen. And Reigen asked back "what do you mean?" in anime version. So I think his exorcising doesn't work on human.

Comment: If it is in a specific episode or manga chapter, please include them. If you have other scenes you used as basis, then include them, too.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I rewatched the scene and he didn't say that. The second one is purely speculation.

Comment: In the anime he said he wouldnt use powers against humans. But later in the fight at the end of the 1st season he did. He even had to use his powers against a woman, didnt he?

Comment: Yes, he did and at the end of season one we can see he reverted back to his principle by his sishou